# How do i step by step evaluate this Complex number expression?

Tags: complex-numbers

$$-\frac32(-\sqrt{3i})$$

I know that|$-\sqrt 3+i|$ can be evaluated to 2. Is it some way i can use that to evaluate the expression?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your mathematical expressions. Also, could you edit your post to include some of your thoughts?

Comment: What do you know about complex numbers? In your example, do you know how this absolute value is calculated?

Comment: I know a little bit. but dont know how |- sqrt(3) +  i | = 2. But is that expression useful to solve my main expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think by evaluating this expression you mean to bring it into cartesian form $a+bi,\,a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. Let's evaluate
$$\sqrt{3i}=\sqrt{3}\cdot\sqrt{i}$$
first. This is not an equation that's why it only has one simplification, if we consider the principal square root. One usually would find the square root of $i$ by the polar form. I have the feeling you are new to complex numbers so I will choose an easier way to follow.

Let's say that the square root of $i$ will equal $a+bi$. Now we have to find out $a$ and $b$:
\begin{align}
\sqrt i &= a+bi\\
i&=(a+bi)^2\\
0+1\cdot i&=a^2-b^2+2abi.
\end{align}
If we compare real and imaginary parts we get $a^2-b^2=0$ and $2abi=1$. This is an easy $2\times2$ linear system of equations. I think you should be able to solve that and get to
$$a=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2},\quad b= \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}.$$ Remember how we defined $a$ and $b$. In conclusion we have
$$\sqrt i = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}i.$$
Let's get back to our original equation. The negative signs eliminate each other and we are left with
$$\frac{3}{2}\sqrt 3\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}i\right)=\frac{3\sqrt 3}{2\sqrt 2}+\frac{3\sqrt 3}{2\sqrt 2}i.$$

Comment: Thanks you very much <3